# Numerical integration for integrals 7th order.

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, matlab

I need to calculate integral which looks like below, with some numerical method:
$\int\limits_{0}^{a}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7) dn_1 dn_2 dn_3 dn_4 dn_5 dn_6 dn_7$
But, when I tried to find some numerical methods which can do it, I don't found anything. Also, I'm found Matlab some functions for simple integral, double, and triple integrals, but no functions for integrals with higher order. Same for scipy Python library.

Maybe anyone deal with same tasks, and tried to solve more than triple integrals with numerical methods?

Comment: The function $f$ doesn't have any separate terms that you can move any of the $n_i$ out of the innermost integral? Have you tried simplifying (or even evaluating) the expression symbolically?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696212/nested-numerical-integration/19715327#19715327) might help you get started. Basically, for each integral you write a function that evaluates it numerically for given parameters, and each inner integral function is used in the next outer integral function. Not elegant, but might work.

Comment: horchler, this function can't be simplified, because $f(n_1,\dotsc,n_7)$ might  vary. Also, for all of my $f()$ Matlab wrote this warning: `Warning: Explicit integral could not be found`.

Comment: A. Donda, I think it makes sense in my situation. I'll try to implement this tricky method.

Comment: Methods like gauss-legendre can be extended to multiple integrals.

Comment: But Gauss-Laguerre seems to be better here becuase of the infinite integral limits.

Comment: @ArtemAgasiev: Note that the "`Warning: Explicit integral could not be found`" warning does not necessarily mean that `sym/int` can't numerically solve the integral, only that it can't find a symbolic solution. I didn't realize this myself until recently. See [this StackOverflow/Matlab question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082581/explicit-integral-could-not-be-found/20083274#comment29920472_20083274) for details.

Answer (score 0):

One technique that may be useful is [Monte-Carlo Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration).  From the wikipedia page, "This method is particularly useful for higher dimensional integrals." The difficulty you may face is with the infinite limits on the inner integrals.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/cody/problems/179-monte-carlo-integration) may have some useful information.